# Protege reasoners cannot infer inverse property

Tags: owl, protege, reasoning, object-properties

I have a simple ontology with a class "Person" that has 3 individuals 'A','B','C'. They are related each other by an object property named `isFatherOf`, for example,

```
A isFatherOf B
B isFatherOf C
```

and I set another property `hasFather`, which is an Inverse property of `isFaterOf`. I expected the reasoner infer:

```
B hasFatherOf A
C hasFatherOf B
```

However, None of the built-in reasoner (FaCT++, HermiT, Pellet) didn't infer them.

Plus, I want to make a property chain of `isFatherOf`, say `isGrandFatherOf`:

```
A isGrandFatherOf C
```

Therfore, I set the SuperProperty like below:

```
isFatherOf o isFatherOf SubPropertyOf isGrandFatherOf
```

but it also fails.

I have the same results on Protege 4.3 and 5.0.0 (Build RC1) with HermiT 1.3.8, Pellet 2.2.0 and FaCT++ 1.6.4. I've searched docs and questions on the internet, but still can't figure out why it is happening. [Here](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/567768/question.owl) is the link for the owl file.

[image]

## Possible Bug Report Added

The problem might be caused from a bug. I had the desired inference results in the environment of: Win7 64-bit, Protege 5-beta21 (and Protege 5-RC1), java 1.8.0_20.

But the problem did occur in the environment of: Win10 64-bit, Protege 5-beta21 (and Protege 5-RC1), java 1.8.0_73. I couldn't get any inference results. I've tried the inference with 3 different reasoners (HermiT 1.3.8, Pellet 2.2.0 and FaCT++ 1.6.4). Among them, only HermiT 1.3.8 shows the error message below. The log says win8 but it's actually win10.
[image][image][image]

Comment: I haven't experienced problems with inference on inverse object properties or the property chain axiom. At first glance, I don't see anything unusual with your ontology. If you share the whole file, it might be easier to understand what the problem is.

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov Hi, I've added the file link. thanks for your attention.

Comment: I've downloaded it and made a quick test. All inferences work as expected with Protégé 5 build 24, Pallet reasoner. Later today I might be able to have a closer look if you or somebody else doesn't figure until then.

Comment: Based on the assertions, Pallet, Hermit 1.3.8.413, Fact++ infer that `A isGrandFatherOf C` , `B hasFather A`, and `C hasFather B`. Only Hermit 1.3.8 returns error in Protégé 5b24. As I trust mainly Pallet, can you please share what is the error that you get when you run Pallet. As you probably know it won't appear as pop-up.

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov yes, you're right. I have the problem only when I run it on Win10. Please check the contents I added.

Comment: I'm using also Win10 64-bit. Why don't you install Protege 5-beta25 and try with Pallet?